# How to debug in safari

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, console.log, javascript-debugger

I am beginner in Web,I am new to `safari browser`.

I am debugging a code in safari.

I used to do some basic calculations and check some `console` statements in browser console during `debugging`.

I tried some simple codes.

But the following two statements return error in safari.

```
 1+1
```

and

```
console.log("I am in Safari console")
```

Please suggest me a solution

> Please inform if any setting changes are required ?
>
> The above statements works good in `chrome`,`firefox`,`internet explorer`

Comment: The code that i am editing is in strict mode, is this the problem ?

Comment: After removing the strict mode,the above code is working.
Please anybody explains why

Answer (score 0):

You have no semicolons `;` after your lines of code? Also I'm not sure what 1+1 is meant to do?

```
var i = 1+1;
console.log("I am in Safari console");
```

Can I suggest a basic Javascript learning resource such as [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)?

Comment: Thank You for your response @ian-grainger

Comment: ; is not must for javascript statements,
The above code works fine in chrome,safari,Internet explorer

Comment: @Venkat thank me by upvoting and accepting the answer - not by commenting! ;) It is in the middle of statements. The parser ignores whitespace, so your statement is equivalent to: `1+1console.log("I am in Safari console")`. Not brilliant, right? :)

Comment: @Venkat I see. No Safari here. Very strange that basic commands in the console don't work. You'll need to give us the error message. And try on a page that definitely doesn't have any other errors.